# ASP.NET Best method to check if email exist in database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery

We have an asp.net web application and we currently use the update panel on user registration page to check if user exists. There are a few issues in doing this

1- update panel is slow

2- when a user tabs to the next textbox the focus is lost so user has to click manually back at the box, this is even worse when the update panel is in a popup

3- even though it does not refresh the page the page load methods are still called, when I only need to call the event fired.

We are using web forms as opposed to asp.net mvc

Our question is what is the best method to do this operation: check if username already exists.

client side:  Regular JavaScript, JQuery, JSON, other possibilities?
Server side to check if user exists: another aspx page, web service, other possibilities?

What other techniques are possible or do you guys use?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, from the client side: http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/XPd2G/2/

I created a simple plugin called `delayedkeyup`, which fires an event after the user stops typing after several milliseconds. When the event does fire, I make an ajax call (in the example, it's a mocked JSON endpoint; you'd replace this with a call to your web service, or page method marked with `WebMethod`, which does a simple DB lookup). The ajax call returns a JSON message indicating whether or not the email is valid.

I add a visual indicator as to the result (green outline is good, red is bad). You could replace this with whatever validation scheme you use, or display a message, whatever.

Note: if you do not like the validation using delayedkeyup, you could just replace it with `.blur` or `.change`, so the lookup is done when the user clicks or tabs out of the textbox, or changes the value (respectively).

The `WebMethod` might look something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string ValidateEmail(string email)
{
   var valid = IsEmailValid(email); // your validation routine
   return string.Format("{{ \"validEmail\":{0} }}", valid.ToString().ToLower());
}
```